# Convert this HQL to Criteria

Tags: java, hql, criteria, criteria-api

I have the following HQL statement:

```
select auditRecord from AuditRecordEntity auditRecord where auditRecord.auditAccount.accountId = :accountId
```

I'd like to convert it to use the javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder, but am unsure what do do, any help is much appreciated!

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object> query = builder.createQuery();
Root<AuditRecordEntity> root = query.from(AuditRecordEntity.class);
// what next?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<AuditRecordEntity> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(AuditRecordEntity.class);
Root<AuditRecordEntity> root = criteriaQuery.from(AuditRecordEntity.class);

Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("auditAccount").get("accountId"), accountId);
criteriaQuery.where(predicate);

TypedQuery<AuditRecordEntity> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

return query.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Thanks @guardian, this worked well, I have another more complex one as well :-) here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909975/convert-this-hql-query-to-criteria

Comment: I think Ramzan Zafars Solution is far superior to this one, code wise.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like following

```
public List<UserProfile> getAuditRecords(String acountId) {

        Criteria auditCriteria = session.createCriteria(AuditRecordEntity.class);
        auditCriteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

        auditCriteria.createCriteria("auditAccount").add(Restrictions.eq("accountId ",acountId));

        return auditCriteria .list();
    }
```

Comment: Why the second `.createCriteria("auditAccount")` call?

Comment: as he need to check on auditAccount which is the child object of AuditRecordEntity as he mentioned in his question auditRecord.auditAccount.accountId